# Moving a 2d character based on local rotation using physics in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, rigid-bodies

I have found a solution for this if I were to be using translation as a means of movement:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1035804/how-do-you-make-an-omnidirectional-2d-character-co.html

however I cannot find a solution for how to do this with my movement being physics based.

I have in my chracters controller the ability to rotate the camera around the z axis:

```
public Transform target;
private float cameraRot = 3;

 if (Input.GetKey("q"))
    {
        target.transform.Rotate(0, 0, cameraRot);
    }
```

I then have a script on all sprites in the world I am creating that rotates to always face the camera:

```
    public Transform target;

void Start () {
    target = GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<Transform>();
}

void Update () {

    if (target != null)

        this.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
}
```

That all works fine. However when I have rotated the camera, and therefore the sprites. The rigidbody movements become all skewed as they are rotating in the "global" space and not the "local".

I have tried placing the facecamera script on the child objects only to leave the rigidbody alone but this has no effect.

I hope I made this clear enough and that someone can help.

thank you very much for your time, if I find a solution I will mark the answer as correct and if I fix this myself before an answer I will update with how I fixed it.

Comment: Ofcourse I managed to solve this issue under 10 minutes after I asked it even though I have tried to fix it for hours.

The solution was to change:

 rigid.AddForce(Vector2.down * speed);

to

 rigid.Add**Relative**Force(Vector2.down * speed);

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html

Hope this helps someone facing the same issue.

Comment: please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that other people know this is resolved

Comment: Done, ill mark it as correct as soon as I can. thanks for letting me know. kinda new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```
Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.down * speed);
```

in lieu of:

```
Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.down * speed);
```

that adds the force in the local axis not the global.

documentation is here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html